# How to switch a function from a class component to a function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, function, class, components

I used to use class components in react-native. My new app.js file looks like this :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import AppContext from './AppContext';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Splash from './src/components/Splash';
import {MainStackNavigator, BottomTabNavigator} from './Navigation/StackNavigator';

export default function App() {

  Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
  Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false; 

  const [user, setUser] = useState({ loggedIn: false });
  const state = { user, setUser };
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 2000);
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={state}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {!user.loggedIn ? (
          <MainStackNavigator />
        ) : (
          <BottomTabNavigator />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

How can I add what I used before, componentDidMount or componentWillMount?
Because here I would like to add this, and i'm a little lost:

```
  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [React.useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

like this:

```
  async someFunction() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
  }
  //this will call at each render
  React.useEffect(() => {
    someFunction()
  });
```

**Be warned:** not to add async keyword inside the useEffect itself or it will cause a crash to your app

Answer (score 1):

As the componentWillMount has been deprecated from the React latest version so, it might not work.

We can move the componentWillMount code to componentDidMount to execute the code without any React warning.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
        i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the declaration of your `languageSetup` is wrong. You need to do like this, if you want a arrow function:

```
const languageSetup = async () => {
  //Your function code
}
```

or

````
async function languageSetup(){
  //Your function code
}
```.
````

Comment: I still have this vut the ap works Warning: useEffect received a final argument that is not an array (instead, received `object`). When specified, the final argument must be an array.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to put the useEffect like this: ```useEffect(()=>{// Your function code},[])```